# Capybara querying doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to test my application with cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit, spork and rspec and I am experiencing an error.

`page.hast_text?("whatever")` passes every time no matter what i pass to the function.

Any Idea how to fix this?

[env.rb](https://gist.github.com/1388814)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing the following with Capybara:

```
page.should have_content("whatever")
```

Or

```
assert page.has_content?("whatever")
```

Comment: Cool.  Could you please vote the answer up and/or accept it?  Thanks!